# A higher level tool for writing a pass in LLVM

Tags: c++, c, llvm

Normally If you want to modify LLVM IR, you need to write a pass. However, writing a pass by yourself is an overkill sometimes if a higher level tool could facilitate you.

For example, someone might wish to log every `load` and `store` in the program. For that purpose, he would need to inject code that does the logging. Now if there is a higher level tool, it can provide callbacks to us to write what we want. So in this case, for example, it could provide us `OnLoad` and `OnStore` functions which we can fill to tell the tool what to do on each load and store. Does such kind of a tool exist?

So basically I want something similar to what is provided by Dynamic Binary Instrumentation tools but that works with LLVM, for compile time code injection.

Comment: Did you inspect the existing LLVM API, and if so, what did you find lacking? I recall the LLVM API being powerful enough to do things like that in a few lines of code, though I never worked with it.

Comment: They are powerful enough for sure, but still I think some tasks can be more easily done if a higher level tool exist. For example in this case, logging every load and store with the address they are loading or storing to, although can be done by writing a pass, but ofcourse is not gonna be as simple as telling a tool what to do by simply implementing OnLoad and OnStore functions. It will be like 10 times easier to do that with a tool.

Comment: that's something that can be done easily with a little grep-fu or sed-fu on the textual representation of the LLVM IR. Or, better yet, with 30 lines of C++ using the LLVM APIs.

Comment: Yes, writing such passes in a language with no pattern matching support is not quite a pleasant experience. You may want to try OCaml or Haskell bindings instead.

Comment: Just be careful with what you do: Emiting extra code for each load/store is horrendous bloat, you can just count loads/stores for each basic block, and update the numbers when the block is entered.

Comment: @SK-logic, perhaps that is the cleanest way. But for somebody who is fooling around with **C** this is painful...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider using PIN instead of LLVM for such things: http://www.pintool.org/

PIN enables you insert instrumentation/analyze code at several granularity levels: instruction, basic block, function, traces and even load/unload of shared libraries. Is may be a way more practical since you won't need to compile the application - so you can analyze programs wich aren't open source for example.

There are version of PIN for windows and linux.

PS: Another tool that seems useful: http://eces.colorado.edu/~blomsted/llvmpin/llvmpin.html